# How to use subscribed data in another request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have post request which will submit the data. Once the data is submitted, I get the response where it contains ID of the item submitted.

That ID I have assigned it to a variable.

Now, I need to use that variable in another post request.

When I'm trying , I can see value is blank

```
 this.sharepointService.createItem().subscribe( (response : Response) => {
      this.lastItemCreatedId = response['d'].ID;  // latitemcreated is a variable
      console.log("Newly created Item ID :" + this.lastItemCreatedId)
    })
```

Now I need to use lastItemCreatedId in another request

```
      let url = "_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl"+"_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List')/items('"+this.lastItemCreatedId+"')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='abc.txt')"

 this.sharepointService.addAttachementstoItem(url).subscribe()
```

Info : Above two are post requests

How can I use lastItemCreatedID variable value in another post request ?

Comment: How is the second post request triggered? Is it called immediately after `createItem()` is called?

Comment: In a Sharpeoint Service I have two different POST requests. One for createItem & another for addAttachmentstoItem. These two requests will be triggered on Submit button  click . Where createItem is triggered first & later addAttachmentstoItem

Comment: In that case, it is actually pretty similar to another question which I have answered a while ago. You may read up more about it here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined/55638270#55638270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both methods are called one after another, you should use RxJS's [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator.

We can use `mergeMap` to map over the observables from the `createItem()` into an inner observable, which will subsequently assigned as part of the `url` variable. Then, we call the addAttachementstoItem() method, and the observables are returned in subscribe() on the subsequent line.

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.sharepointService.createItem()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((response : Response) => {
      this.lastItemCreatedId = response['d'].ID;
      let url = "_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl"+"_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List')/items('"+this.lastItemCreatedId+"')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='abc.txt')"
      return this.sharepointService.addAttachementstoItem(url);
    }).subscribe(res => {
      // do the rest here
    })
```

Comment: Will try that !

Comment: I have tried that, but the return statement is in a loop. So therefore I'm getting the error : Argument of type '(response: Object) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object, index: number) => ObservableInput<unknown>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<unknown>'

Comment: @Shivaay May I know where is the loop at? You mentioned there is a loop in your code?