# RxJs operators avoid multiple subscriptions, with loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm writing a nav component for an Angular app.  I've got the following code.  I want to avoid the multiple subscription anti-pattern.  I am struggling with the RxJs syntax, and which way to go (forkJoin, mergeMap, etc).

How can I refactor these, to remove the subscribe within the subscribe.

Here's what I have, which currently works, but has a subscribe within a subscribe:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ehrcc-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  applicationName: string = 'AppName';
  userDisplayName: string = '';
  isAuthorizedUser: boolean = false;
  isAdminUser: boolean = false;

  groupsList: MemberGroup[] = [];

  constructor(private userService:UserService,
    private auditService: UserAuditService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getDisplayName();

    this.userService.getGroupMembershipsForUser().subscribe(members =>{
      this.groupsList = members;
      for (let g of this.groupsList){
        if (g.id === this.userService.usersGroupId){
          this.isAuthorizedUser = true;
          this.router.navigate(['/workItem']);
        }
        if (g.id === this.userService.adminGroupId){
          this.isAdminUser = true;
        }
      }
      this.logUserInfo();   <---- ANTI-PATTERN
     });

  }

  getDisplayName(){
    this.userService.getSignedInAzureADUser().subscribe(
      (user) => this.userDisplayName = user.displayName,
      (error: any) => {
        return console.log(' Error: ' + JSON.stringify(<any>error));
    });
  }

  logUserInfo(){
    var audit = new UserAudit();
    audit.Application = this.applicationName;
    audit.Environment = "UI";
    audit.EventType= "Authorization";
    audit.UserId = this.userDisplayName;
    audit.Details = ` User Is Authorized: ${this.isAuthorizedUser}, User Is Admin: ${this.isAdminUser}`;

    this.auditService.logUserInfo(audit)
    .subscribe({ 
      next: (id)=> console.log('Id created: '+ id),
      error: (error: any) => console.log(' Error: ' + JSON.stringify(<any>error) )
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use the map operator in your Observable and emit your data modified? can you post your source Observable¿?

Comment: Personally I recommend to use ngrx Statemanagement for such tasks. Chaining actions can be much easier then joining responses. And of course it is easiert to test them.

Comment: @Robertgarcia  I have posted the source observable, or what I think you mean when you are asking for the source observable.  It shows what I had to do to get the original data out of another API.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm  Thanks for the comment.  I have not used the technology you are speaking of.

Comment: So you need to call the logUserInfo once you got all the info from your subscriptions? You can use forkJoin() to emit an observable once all your subscriptions complete() so you will have all your data ready in the forkJoin subscription, if thats not the case i think you need to explain more the problem you are facing

Comment: Thanks for your patience, @Robertgarcia.  Yes, I want to call the logUserInfo method once I have done the logic.  I just am struggling with how to write the forkJoin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - two subscriptions in ngOnInit result in object 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined)

Comment: @JenniferS Apart from that, you can use `mergeMap` to handle your scenario. This will ensure that the observable from `getSignedInAzureADUser` will be returned before `getGroupMembershipsForUser ` is executed. This way, `userDisplayName ` will definitely be defined when `logUserInfo ` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I was searching why some `subscribe` code blocks were being executed multiple times with no apparent reason.

I found out that this was due to services that returned some *Observables* which were not yet loaded with the proper data. Thus I solved this issue with **[auditTime](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime)** which:

> Ignores source values for `duration` milliseconds, then emits the most recent value from the source *Observable*.

Therefore, using the question's code, a **[pipe](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pipe)** can be added with that operator:

```
import { auditTime, ... } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.userService.getGroupMembershipsForUser().
 .pipe(auditTime(1E3)) // delays for 1 second and gets the most recent value
 .subscribe(members => { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

```
forkJoin({
   displayName: this.userService.getSignedInAzureADUser() // This will give you the 
   observable subscription value,
   groupMemberShip:this.userService.getGroupMembershipsForUser() 
})
```

Once you subscribe to that forkJoin you will get an object with all the values and you can call the logUserInfo from it, all the observables needs to complete() in order to emit the forkJoin