# Angular - Multiple subscribe sequence doesn´t work

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular i want to create a multiple subscribe sequence. When the first subscribe is complete do next subscribe. Similar to this.

```
this.globalCtrl.getSon().subscribe(
                  response => {
                    this.son= response;
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log(error);
                  },
                  () => {
                   //DOESN´T ENTER IN THIS SUBSCRIBE
                    this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(this.son).subscribe(

                      response => {
                        this.markers = response["body"]["data"];
                        if (this.markers.length == 0) {
                          this.toast.fire({
                            type: "error",
                            title: "No hay datos geográficos del grupo seleccionado"
                          });
                        }
                        this.timezone = response["body"]["timezone"];
                      },
                      error => {
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                    );
```

The problem: Doesn't enter in the second subscription and the  'response' has data. ¿Anyone know how can i do that?

**UPDATE**

If i put second subscription inside response like this

```
  this.globalCtrl.getSon().subscribe(
                      response => {
                        this.son= response;
                        this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(this.son).subscribe(

                          response => {
                            this.markers = response["body"]["data"];
                            if (this.markers.length == 0) {
                              this.toast.fire({
                                type: "error",
                                title: "No hay datos geográficos del grupo seleccionado"
                              });
                            }
                            this.timezone = response["body"]["timezone"];
                          },
                          error => {
                            console.log(error);
                          }
                        );
```

Works but view doesn´t show data. When i refresh the view data load properly, but in first load doesn´t load data.

**UPDATE 2: USING SWITCH MAP**

```
  this.globalCtrl.getfather().pipe(
      switchMap(son=> this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(son.toString()).subscribe( /ERROR
        response => {
          this.markers = response["body"]["data"];
          if (this.markers.length == 0) {
            this.toast.fire({
              type: "error",
              title: "No hay datos geográficos del grupo seleccionado"
            });
          }
          this.timezone = response["body"]["timezone"];
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    );
```

> The propierty subscribe doesn´t exist in OperatorFunction

Maybe the observable cause the error

```
 getFather(): Observable<any> {
    return this.grupo.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - two subscriptions in ngOnInit result in object 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined)

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting multiple `subscribe()` methods within the same `subscribe()` block! It is very bad practice when it comes to handling observables. Instead, you should be making use of RxJS operators such as `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, or even `forkJoin`, depending on the requirements and flow of data. You may refer to this as well. [Angular Subscribe within Subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447803/angular-subscribe-within-subscribe/55447947#55447947)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you do *not* nest a subscribe inside another subscribe. It makes it difficult to manage and just about impossible to correctly unsubscribe. Instead, use `switchMap`.

Here is an example from one of my sample apps:

```
  todosForUser$ = this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${this.userName}`)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(user =>
        this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${user.id}`)
      )
    );
```

You can see this code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk

Using your code, it would be something like this (NOT syntax checked):

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.globalCtrl.getSon()
 .pipe(
    switchMap(son => this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(son))
 ).subscribe(...);
```

UPDATE: Simplified initial example, which originally demonstrated how to handle *multiple* related datasets.

Comment: Be sure to import it as shown above, and be sure to spell it `switchMap` (little 's')

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other answers make use of nested `subscribe()`, which isn't the Angular/RxJS way of doing things

Comment: Looks like your parentheses aren't quite right: `switchMap(son=> this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(son))).subscribe` You need to close the `pipe()` before subscribing. See above that I have *3* closing parens.

Comment: switchMap will work but for his case mergeMap would fit better.

Comment: I had been using `mergeMap` as well ... but *every* example I found anywhere that discussed nested subscribes use `switchMap`. I normally only used switchMap if I really want to switch (like when getting data on user button clicks).

Comment: @DeborahK would u check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432169/rxjs-subscribe-inside-subscribe-with-each-level-returns-values-and-store-into-re                                                    
. i'm stuck with 4 level Nested Subscription

Answer (score 1):

Your second subscription is put in a wrong place. It should be inside the response of a first subscription

```
this.globalCtrl.getSon().subscribe(
                  response => {
                    this.son= response;
                    // ADD THE OTHER SUBSCRIBE HERE
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
```

The observable callback has 3 types - `next`, `error`, `complete`

You were putting the second subscription in a `complete` callback and that was the reason it was never called (Your first observable never completed).

Read more about Observables [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your second subscription inside your first one:

```
this.globalCtrl.getSon().subscribe(
              response => {
                this.son= response;
                  this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(this.son).subscribe(
                  response => {
                    this.markers = response["body"]["data"];
                    if (this.markers.length == 0) {
                      this.toast.fire({
                        type: "error",
                        title: "No hay datos geográficos del grupo seleccionado"
                      });
                    }
                    this.timezone = response["body"]["timezone"];
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              } 
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a subscription inside a subscription is called **Flattening**

In response to [@DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk) answer using `switchMap` would work, but it would be a misuse of it. `switchMap` would be a way to go if your first observable could change while there's a subscription already to it. Better approach would be to use `mergeMap` also (previously) known as `flatMap`

**mergeMap** - Use it when you have an Observable whose results are another Observable

**switchMap** - Use it when you have an Observable that can change and whose results are another Observable

If your first Observable emits something, mergeMap wouldn't discard the previous Observable, therefore your inner subscription would still be subscribed to the previous one. In switchMap it would discard the previous Observable and inner subscription would subscribe to the inner one.

The solution:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap';
.......
.......

this.globalCtrl.getSon().pipe(
  mergeMap((response) => {
    this.son = response;
    return this.dashboardCtrl.getMarkers(this.son)
  })
).subscribe((res) => {
  this.markers = response["body"]["data"];
});
```

Comment: what if there is more than two level? Please Check this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432169/rxjs-subscribe-inside-subscribe-with-each-level-returns-values-and-store-into-re