# RxJS subscribe inside subscribe with each level returns values and store into respective variables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know already there are posts regarding the Nested Subscribe. Here, we have 5 leveled subscribeoperation with each variables (operationId,actionlistId,componentId,traceId). Here Apis are calling whose function is given below.

**Step 1:** orderTemplateId to `api` GetOperationTemplate, will get values operationModel and operationId.
**Step 2:** operationId to `api` GetActionTemplate, will get values actionId, actionListId and actionModel.
**Step 3:** actionId to `api` GetComponentUsageTemplate, will get values componentId and componentModel.
**Step 4:** componentId/ to `api` GetTraceTemplate, will get values traceId and traceModel.

**OLD WORKING CODE** Which is causing delay.

```
  onOrderTemplateClick(selectedData: any): void {
    this.selectedData = selectedData;
    this.descOrderTemplate = selectedData.name;
    this.orderTemplateId = selectedData.id;
    this.orderTemplateFormGroup.controls['orderTemplate'].setValue(this.descOrderTemplate);
    console.log('OperationTemplate');

    this.ordertemplateService.GetOperationTemplate(this.orderTemplateId)
     .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.operationModel = res;
        if (Object.keys(this.operationModel).length > 0) {
          console.log(this.operationModel);
          console.log('ActionList');
          this.ordertemplateService.GetActionTemplate(this.operationModel[0].id)
             .subscribe((res1: any) => {
              this.actionModel = res1;

              if (Object.keys(this.actionModel).length > 0) {
                this.actionId = res1[0].id;
                this.actionListId = res1[0].parentId;
                console.log(this.actionModel);
                console.log('Action Parameters');

                this.ordertemplateService.GetActionParameterTemplate(this.actionModel[0].parentId)
                 .subscribe((res2: any) => {
                    if (Object.keys(res2).length > 0) {
                      this.actionParamModel = res2;
                      this.actionParameterId = res2[0].id;
                      this.actionParameterId = this.actionParamModel[0].id;
                    } else {
                      this.initializeActionParameterComponentTrace();
                    }
                  });

                console.log('Component Usage');
                this.ordertemplateService.GetComponentUsageTemplate(this.actionModel[0].id)
                 .subscribe((res3: any) => {
                    this.componentModel = res3;
                    this.componentId = res3[0].id;
                    if (Object.keys(this.componentModel).length > 0) {
                      console.log(this.componentModel);
                      console.log('Component Usage');
                      this.ordertemplateService.GetTraceTemplate(this.componentModel[0].parentId)
                        .subscribe((res4: any) => {
                          this.traceModel = res4;
                          if (Object.keys(this.traceModel).length > 0) {
                            this.traceId = res4[0].id;
                            console.log(this.traceModel);
                            console.log('Trace Usage');
                          } else {
                            this.initializeTrace();
                          }

                        });
                    } else {
                      this.traceActions(this.actionModel[0].id);

                    }
                  });


              } else {
                this.initializeComponentTrace();
              }
            }
            );
        } else {
          this.initializeAll();
        }


      });
  }
```

**NEW WORKING CODE** which I am trying using switchmap.

```
 onOrderTemplateClick(selectedData: any): void {
    this.selectedData = selectedData;
    this.descOrderTemplate = selectedData.name;
    this.orderTemplateId = selectedData.id;
    this.orderTemplateFormGroup.controls['orderTemplate'].setValue(this.descOrderTemplate);
    console.log('OperationTemplate');
    this.ordertemplateService.GetOperationTemplate(this.orderTemplateId)
    .pipe(
    switchMap((opData)=> {        
            this.operationModel = opData;
            if (Object.keys(this.operationModel).length > 0) {
              console.log(this.operationModel);
        } else {
                    this.initializeAll();
                }
        }),
    switchMap((actData)=> {
        console.log('ActionList');
            this.actionModel=this.ordertemplateService.GetActionTemplate(this.operationModel[0].id); // actdata[0].id
         if (Object.keys(this.actionModel).length > 0) {
                    this.actionId = this.actionModel[0].id;
                    this.actionListId = this.actionModel[0].parentId;
                    console.log(this.actionModel);
            console.log('Action Parameters');
                    this.actionParamModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetActionParameterTemplate(this.actionModel[0].parentId);
            if (Object.keys(this.actionModel).length > 0) {
            this.actionParameterId = this.actionParamModel[0].id;
            console.log(this.actionParamModel);
            } else {
            this.initializeActionComponentTrace();
            }       
        } else {
                    this.initializeActinonactionParameterComponentTrace();
                }
        }),
    switchMap((cmpData)=> {
        console.log('Component Usage');
        this.componentModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetComponentUsageTemplate(this.actionModel[0].id); // cmpData[0].id
        this.componentId = this.componentModel[0].id;
        if (Object.keys(this.componentModel).length > 0) {
                      console.log(this.componentModel);
                      console.log('Component Usage');
        } else {
                    this.initializeComponentTrace();
                }       
        }),
    switchMap((traceData)=> {
        this.traceModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetTraceTemplate(this.componentModel[0].parentId); // cmpData[0].id
                if (Object.keys(this.traceModel).length > 0) {
                     this.traceId = this.traceModel[0].id;
                     console.log(this.traceModel);
                     console.log('Trace Usage')
         } else {
                     this.initializeTrace();
                 }

    }))
    .subscribe((data)=> {
        if(data!= undefined) {
        console.log(data);
        }
  })
}
```

The below code causes delay of 10 sec(max). Is Nested Subscribe related to delay?

Comment: If I had this problem I would change your observables to promises and use the async/await pattern.

Comment: try to measure how many milliseconds takes every http call

Comment: @StepUp its 150ms to 172ms. But there is large amount of data that's why too much delay.

Comment: Is there any wrong in the above new code? @Mickers

Comment: @wentjun, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any control over the back-end? You could potentially improve performance by adding APIs that allowed retrieving some of the related data in one call instead of multiple calls.

Comment: i added 5 Api's .These functions are used to call api's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there is nothing wrong with your code (I am referring to your updated code). However, I do realise that within each `switchMap()` operator sequence, you aren't really emitting any new observable values, hence that isn't really the right way to use RxJs's switchMap() operator.

As described on the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), switchMap allows you to

> Map to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values.

Therefore, it might be more appropriate to use the [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator, as you are merely performing side effects in sequence, and returning to source observable at the end of the chain when you subscribe to it.

```
onOrderTemplateClick(selectedData: any): void {
  this.selectedData = selectedData;
  this.descOrderTemplate = selectedData.name;
  this.orderTemplateId = selectedData.id;
  this.orderTemplateFormGroup.controls['orderTemplate'].setValue(this.descOrderTemplate);
  console.log('OperationTemplate');
  this.ordertemplateService.GetOperationTemplate(this.orderTemplateId)
    .pipe(
      tap((opData) => {
        this.operationModel = opData;
        if (Object.keys(this.operationModel).length > 0) {
          console.log(this.operationModel);
        } else {
          this.initializeAll();
        }
      }),
      tap((actData) => {
        console.log('ActionList');
        this.actionModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetActionTemplate(this.operationModel[0].id); // actdata[0].id
        if (Object.keys(this.actionModel).length > 0) {
          this.actionId = this.actionModel[0].id;
          this.actionListId = this.actionModel[0].parentId;
          console.log(this.actionModel);
          console.log('Action Parameters');
          this.actionParamModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetActionParameterTemplate(this.actionModel[0].parentId);
          if (Object.keys(this.actionModel).length > 0) {
            this.actionParameterId = this.actionParamModel[0].id;
            console.log(this.actionParamModel);
          } else {
            this.initializeActionComponentTrace();
          }
        } else {
          this.initializeActinonactionParameterComponentTrace();
        }
      }),
      tap((cmpData) => {
        console.log('Component Usage');
        this.componentModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetComponentUsageTemplate(this.actionModel[0].id); // cmpData[0].id
        this.componentId = this.componentModel[0].id;
        if (Object.keys(this.componentModel).length > 0) {
          console.log(this.componentModel);
          console.log('Component Usage');
        } else {
          this.initializeComponentTrace();
        }
      }),
      tap((traceData) => {
        this.traceModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetTraceTemplate(this.componentModel[0].parentId); // cmpData[0].id
        if (Object.keys(this.traceModel).length > 0) {
          this.traceId = this.traceModel[0].id;
          console.log(this.traceModel);
          console.log('Trace Usage')
        } else {
          this.initializeTrace();
        }

      }))
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if (data != undefined) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
}
```

With regards to the delay, that is probably because it is quite a long sequence, and that you are invoking quite a number of operations, which is why it takes a long time to finish running it. I would recommend you to remove any function calls that do not require it to be run in sequence, and call them outside the observable flow.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct. So you need to figure out what part of code gets so many time. I suggest you to use [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) method to measure your code:

```
console.log(`1. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
this.ordertemplateService.GetOperationTemplate(this.orderTemplateId)
.pipe(
switchMap((opData)=> {        
    console.log(`2. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
    }),
switchMap((actData)=> {
    console.log('ActionList');

switchMap((cmpData)=> {
    console.log(`3. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
    this.componentModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetComponentUsageTemplate(this.actionModel[0].id); // cmpData[0].id
    this.componentId = this.componentModel[0].id;
    if (Object.keys(this.componentModel).length > 0) {
                  console.log(this.componentModel);
                  console.log('Component Usage');
    } else {
                this.initializeComponentTrace();
            }       
    console.log(`4. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
    }),
switchMap((traceData)=> {
    console.log(`5. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
    this.traceModel = this.ordertemplateService.GetTraceTemplate(this.componentModel[0].parentId); // cmpData[0].id
            if (Object.keys(this.traceModel).length > 0) {
                 this.traceId = this.traceModel[0].id;
                 console.log(this.traceModel);
                 console.log('Trace Usage')
     } else {
                 this.initializeTrace();
             }

    console.log(`6. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
}))
.subscribe((data)=> {
    if(data!= undefined) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(`7. performance.now() ${performance.now()}`);
    }
})
```

Then you will have an iformation, what piece of code is takes so many time.