# How to compare sum of two strings from firebase

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm making an application that calculate mileage of vehicule , so i'm making now page of rappel so the user put his maintenance schedule.

I read the mileage of vehicule and the mileage of maintenance schedule but i got this **error**

> i can't compare sum of two values read it from database (firebase)

pic 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTqyM.jpg

pic 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J7cd.jpg

**rappel.service.ts :**

```
constructor(private crudService: RappelService,private cr:VoitureService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.crudService.read_Rappel().subscribe(data => {
      this.cvoiture=localStorage.getItem("idvoiture");
      this.rappels = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          text: e.payload.doc.data()['text'],
          rappelNom: e.payload.doc.data()['rappelNom'],
          rappelKilo: e.payload.doc.data()['rappelKilo'],
  cvoiture:e.payload.doc.data()['voiture'],
  rappelService:e.payload.doc.data()['rappelService'],
        };
      })
      console.log(this.rappels);
    });
    this.cr.read_Voiture().subscribe(data => {
      this.voitures = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          text: e.payload.doc.data()['text'],
          mat: e.payload.doc.data()['mat'],
          date: e.payload.doc.data()['date'],
          description: e.payload.doc.data()['description'],
          id_user: e.payload.doc.data()['id_user'],
        kilo: e.payload.doc.data()['kilo']
        };
      } )
      console.log(this.voitures);
      console.log(this.voitures[0].kilo);
      console.log(this.rappels[0].rappelKilo);
      console.log(this.rappels[0].rappelService);
      console.log(this.rappels[0].rappelKilo+this.rappels[0].rappelService)
    });
    if (this.voitures[0].kilo<(this.rappels[0].rappelKilo+this.rappels[0].rappelService)) {
      console.log(this.rappels[0].rappelNom);
    }
  }
```

I expect to compare `voitures[0].kilo` with sum of `this.rappels[0].rappelKilo` and`this.rappels[0].rappelService` and get the name of service appear it in console but i get error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - two subscriptions in ngOnInit result in object 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined)

Comment: Thank you for replay but I didn't understand sir

Comment: This might be a bit more advanced than what you're looking for but you should check out this [tutorial on data aggregation](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-cloud-functions-data-aggregation/). Selecting chunks of records to sum them will cost money in the long run, better to pre-calculate it.

Comment: If you dont understand the duplicate question that you have been directed to then you need to learn more about rxjs. There are a lot of good tutorial videos on youtube.

Comment: Just i want to know how can i do a sum of two values read it from firebase that's all, i read it but i can't do sum

Comment: @MOHAMED it is actually quite similar to the question I flagged - you can use forkJoin, or mergeMap. If you still can't get it, I will submit an answer

Comment: @wentjun Please!

Comment: @MOHAMED I have submitted my approach. Do let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for this scenario..

The idea of how `forkJoin` works is that it requires the input observables to be completed, and it will eventually be used to return an observable represented by an array, which consists of the values returned by the input observables.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
  const observableA = this.crudService.read_Rappel();
  const observableB = this.cr.read_Voiture();

  forkJoin(observableA, observableB).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // do the rest here
    // this.rappels =
    // this.voitures = 
    // if (this.voitures[0].kilo<(this.rappels[0].rappelKilo+this.rappels[0].rappelService)) {
    // console.log(this.rappels[0].rappelNom);
    // }
  });  
}
```