# Function called in ngOnInit returns empty

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I console.log when the array 'series' gets fully populated. I know ngOnInit is async but how do I get my function to load once it's done processing rather than just console.log right away when no value is filled. I know I can attach a setTimeout but is there another way around this?

Here is what my console.log shows without setTimeout:
[image: 1]

Here is what it shows with setTimeOut(Desired result AKA populated series array)
[image: 2]

My code without setTimeout:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { ParseDataService } from '../../services/parse-data.service'
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { Map } from './mapClass';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recovered',
  templateUrl: './recovered.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recovered.component.css']
})
export class RecoveredComponent implements OnInit {
  globalRecovData: Array<any> = [];
  totalRecovByDate: Array<any> = [];
  totalRecovToday: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private parseData: ParseDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GlobalRecov();
    this.getMapData();
  }

  getMapData() {
    let map = new Map;
    const newMap = map.create({
      date: 'Recovered',
      series: []
    })
    this.totalRecovByDate.map(data => {
        newMap.series.push(data);
      })
      let newArrayMap = [];
      newArrayMap.push(newMap);
      console.log(newArrayMap)
  }

  GlobalRecov(){
      this.dataService.GlobalRecovGet().subscribe((rawdata) => {
        this.globalRecovData = this.parseData.parseGlobalData(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);
        this.totalRecovToday = this.parseData.getTotalToday(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);
        this.totalRecovByDate = this.parseData.getTotalByDate(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);


      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: A rather similar question that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined/55638270#55638270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `dataService.GlobalRecovGet()` is asynchronous, that's why `getMapData()` will run while the response from `GlobalRecov()` is still pending.  Since `getMapData()` utilises `totalRecovByDate`, which is dependent on the response from the service, it will be undefined at that point.

You can consider nesting `getMapData()` within `GlobalRecov()`. This will ensure that `getMapData()` will run after the response from `dataService.GlobalRecovGet()` is returned.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.GlobalRecov();
}

getMapData() {
  let map = new Map;
  const newMap = map.create({
    date: 'Recovered',
    series: []
  });
  this.totalRecovByDate.map(data => {
    newMap.series.push(data);
  })
  let newArrayMap = [];
  newArrayMap.push(newMap);
  console.log(newArrayMap)
}

GlobalRecov(){
  this.dataService.GlobalRecovGet().subscribe((rawdata) => {
    this.globalRecovData = this.parseData.parseGlobalData(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);
    this.totalRecovToday = this.parseData.getTotalToday(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);
    this.totalRecovByDate = this.parseData.getTotalByDate(rawdata, this.globalRecovData);
    this.getMapData();
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done that and it worked. Is there any way to await GlobalRecov()?

Comment: If you are using subscribe, you can't just await it. If you want to use async await, you will have to convert it to a promise, but that is just extra work.